# How to iterate Set of promises? (async)

Tags: javascript, promise, set

I have a Set collection of promises:

```
const testQueue = new Set()

const promise1 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(1))
const promise2 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(1))

testQueue.add(promise1)
testQueue.add(promise2)

testQueue.forEach((promise) => {
  console.log(`[promise]:`, promise)
})
```

As you know, forEach will give me each promise, but if I try to fire it and wait for either resolve or reject, it won't wait and jump to the next item in the collection.

If we store the promises within an array, we can do this:

```
const promises = [p1, p2]

for (const promise of promises) {
  await promise // it will wait between promises
  // of course, inside async function
}
```

Is it possible to iterate async Set collection of promises?

This question can match for Map collection as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I think you want `Promise.all`

Convert your set of Promises into an array.
Then use `Promise.all`

For example:

```
await Promise.all([...testQueue])
```

### What `[... setVariable]` does

The "..." explodes the elements of the set, just as it would do for an array. The `[` and `]` then reassemble the results into an array.

So if you have a set `s`, you can convert it into an array with `[...s]`.

### Promise.all will work with a set directly!

Thanks to @VLAZ in the comments for pointing out that you can just do this:

```
await Promise.all(testQueue)
```

### Remember there is no such thing as an "Async set collection of promises"

Sets are just data structures. Did you mean "set of promises"?

Comment: I didn't know I can Promise.all a Set/Map collections. Thanks. And you shouldn't make the conversion, you can just supply the whole collection as it is.

Comment: "*Put your Promises into an array, rather than a set.*" sets **are iterable**. And `Promise.all` takes an iterable. Why juggle the arrays and sets? And if your suggestion is "use an array" then OP already knows how to handle those anyway.

Comment: The comments are trying to say that you can just do `Promise.all(testQueue)`.